# Cannot access '/dev/video*'

Tags: video, lenovo, camera

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I would really appreciate your help.

I am having an issue with accessing to my web cam from my Lenovo X1 carbon (running Ubuntu 20.04).

```
yuxiang@yuxiang:/etc/modprobe.d$ ls /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory


yuxiang@yuxiang:/etc/modprobe.d$ fswebcam -r 640x480 --no-banner image3.jpg
--- Opening /dev/video0...
stat: No such file or directory
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you verified the directory exists?

Comment: Hi David,  The folder /dev/video does not exist for me...

Comment: Have you tried making the 2 directories and see if the error still happens?